# How to solve this encoding issue in with Spyder in Anaconda (Python 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to run the following:

```
import json
path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt' 
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
```

But I get the following error :

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position
>   6987: ordinal not in range(128)

From the internet I've found that it should be because the encoding needs to be set to utf-8, but my issue is that it's already in utf-8.

```
sys.getdefaultencoding() 
Out[43]: 'utf-8'
```

Also, it looks like my file is in utf-8, so I'm really confused
Also, the following code works :

```
In [15]: path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
In [16]: open(path).readline()
```

Is there a way to solve this ?

Thanks !

***EDIT:***

When I run the code in my console it works, but not when I run it in Spyder provided by Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Do you know what can go wrong ?

Comment: Did you try actually *opening* the file using the encoding?

Comment: What do you mean ? 
 open(path).readline() works well

Comment: You must have downloaded the file incorrectly Are you sure you downloaded it as-is not copy-pasted it through a text editor or something? Your code runs without errors on my system on the exact same file I just downloaded from the location you gave. I've tried Python 3.5.1 on both Windows 7 and Linux.

Comment: I also downloaded that file & had no problem calling `json.loads` on each of its lines, running Python 3.6 on Linux, and it also works fine   on Python 2.6 (with minor changes to account for the way Python 2 does Unicode). FWIW, I got a list of 3560 objects.

Comment: Is it possible that something is wrong with my setup?
I had python 2 installed on my machine, and then I installed python 3 and then anaconda, but when I open my terminal and type 'python' it says still Python 2.7.10 , even if I have anaconda with Python 3 ?

Comment: Update, I've updated my python version which is now also 3.5.2 in my terminal, closed everything and reopened but nothing changed

Comment: You edited your question and now it seems to be an issue with Spyder, and not Python3 perse. Perhaps you should update the question title as well.

Comment: I've edited the post : it appears to work in the normal OS X terminal but not in the anaconda terminal, very confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text file contains some non-ascii characters on a line somewhere. Somehow on your setup the default file encoding is set to ascii instead of utf-8 so do the following and specify the file's encoding explicitly:

```
import json
path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt' 
records = [json.loads(line.strip()) for line in open(path, encoding="utf-8"))]
```

(Doing this is a good idea anyway even when the default works)

Comment: Thanks, it made it work!
But I still don't understand how I can get the error in the first place in spyder and not in my normal terminal.
Especially because my env variable PYTHONIOENCODING = UTF-8, and in both spyder and system console I have sys.getdefaultencoding() giving me utf-8

Comment: because PYTHONIOENCODING has nothing to do with file i/o, it controls the encoding of stdin/stdout/stderr https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING .     Tip: read this http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html

Answer (score 0):

I try to ran this program with one additional line at the top:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

It fetches the lines and shows the output (with u' prefixed strings; probably a conversion might be required after this). But, it didn't throw any error as you mentioned.

Comment: The coding directive has _no_ effect on how a script processes external Unicode data. It's purely used to tell the Python interpreter which encoding has been used for the script itself.